# Why does \includepdfmerge insert a blank page at the end?

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include, blank-page

How can I get rid of the blank pages inserted after the `\includepdfmerge` ?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdfmerge[scale=0.5, delta=10pt 10pt, nup=2x2]{
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1, 
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1,
}

\includepdfmerge[scale=0.5, delta=10pt 10pt, nup=2x2]{
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1,
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1,
}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that removing the last comma, after the last page number definition will do the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdfmerge[scale=0.5, delta=10pt 10pt, nup=2x2]{
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1, 
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1
}

\includepdfmerge[scale=0.5, delta=10pt 10pt, nup=2x2]{
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1,
black.pdf, 1, black.pdf, 1
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: erh, aren't your two MWEs equal? So what exactly did you do differently?

Comment: sorry, "comma", not "column"

Comment: Ahh, now I saw the difference